# Cursor attribute %notfound as exit statement returns confusing results

Tags: sql, oracle, loops

```
DECLARE
  i     employees.first_name%TYPE;
  a     employees.last_name%TYPE;
  j     employees.salary%TYPE;
  v_cnt NUMBER;

  CURSOR c1 IS
    SELECT first_name
          ,last_name
          ,salary
      FROM employees
     WHERE employee_id BETWEEN 100 AND 105;

BEGIN
  OPEN c1;

  LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO i, a, j;

    dbms_output.put_line(i || ' ' || a || ' SALARY IS ' || j || ' row count is ' || v_cnt);

    v_cnt := c1%ROWCOUNT;    
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE c1;
END;
/
```

My above query basically loops through all the `employee_id` between 100 and 105 and prints all 6 employees' salary using `dbms_output.put_line`.

However, I am getting 7 results with the last one a duplicate result of the previous record. See below

```
Steven King SALARY IS 24000 row count is 
Neena Kochhar SALARY IS 17000 row count is 1
Lex De Haan SALARY IS 17000 row count is 2
Alexander Hunold SALARY IS 9000 row count is 3
Bruce Ernst SALARY IS 6000 row count is 4
David Austin SALARY IS 4800 row count is 5
David Austin SALARY IS 4800 row count is 6
```

Why is my result returned like this? And why isn't my cursor rowcount marking the first record as 1?

Comment: Presumably, `David Austin` is in your data twice with an `employee_id` between 100 and 105.  As for the first `v_cnt` value . . .  it is missing because it is initialized *after* the `put_line()`, not before.

Comment: can you post your input? I mean the content of employee table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `v_cnt` is not initialized i.e. `IS NULL` on the first call of `dbms_output.put_line`, so you see an empty line instead of row number in the output.
2. The last fetch makes no action, because there are no more rows in cursor, so variables `i, a, j` doesn't change after last fetch. You may fetch as long as you want, but after the last row has been fetched out of cursor the `FETCH INTO` operator produces no new data.

To get what you need (standard loop behavior) the fetching loop shall be organized as

```
LOOP
    FETCH c1 INTO i, a, j;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
    v_cnt := c1%ROWCOUNT; 

    dbms_output.put_line(i || ' ' || a || ' SALARY IS ' || j || ' row count is ' || v_cnt);

END LOOP;
```

To avoid compliactions with fetching a cursor you can do it using "for loop".
This is an appropriate solution in the most cases, and definitely in the case of example you gave in the question.

```
FOR l_rec IN c1
LOOP

  i := l_rec.first_name;
  a := l_rec.last_name;
  j := l_rec.salary;
  v_cnt := c1%ROWCOUNT;

  dbms_output.put_line(i || ' ' || a || ' SALARY IS ' || j || ' row count is ' || v_cnt);

END LOOP;
```